# Is there an equivalent 'cp --backup=numbered' option for copies across the network?

Tags: linux, scp

I'm looking to simulate what `cp --backup=numbered` does using `scp` or another network copy command.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync has a `-b` flag which appears to do what you want, and has a `-e ssh` flag to enable encryption.  This may be as close as you get.

Comment: Another possibility might be to install remotely a version system (perhaps `git` or `svn`) and access it thru `ssh`

Comment: Close enough but I don't get versioned backup copies of the destination file. I should have been more precise in the question, I'm looking for a cp --backup=numbered equivalent.

Comment: Look at the `--suffix=SUFFIX` flag.  You can probably get, if not numbered versions, at least dated versions with --suffix=.20121012